# Python: Cut tiff by geography and save as individual images

Tags: python, gis, gdal

I have a really weird problem that I can't seem to figure out. I am working with satellite imagery and I want to do a very specific thing. I have two layers (that overlay); one is satellite imagery and another is a bunch of squares. I want to use the squares to cut the much larger satellite image into many smaller images and save each image individually in a folder. Does anyone have any idea where to begin here? I'm guessing gdal is what I need but I can't seem to figure out how to cut and save.

Comment: First you need to read your file.  I'm not sure what's stable and active, but this may be a good starting point: https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC18/lessons/L6/reading-raster.html

Comment: it would indeed be helpful if you could provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In any case, you might want to look at `gdal` and / or `rasterio` together with `fiona` or `geopandas` depending on what your 'layers' are